# Parallelizing subgraph tasks in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, networkx, ipython-parallel

This might be a naive question but I've really tried searching multiple resources: `multiprocessing` and `ipyparallel` but these seem to be lack of appropriate information for my task.

What I have is a large directed graph `G` with 9 million edges and 6 million nodes. My goal is to, for a list of target nodes (**50k**, along with their direct neighbours (both in/out), extract subgraphs from `G`. I am currently using `networkx` to do this.

I tried to use `ipyparallel` but I could not find tutorial on how to share an object (in my case, `G`) across processors for subgraph function. Is there an easy way to parallelize this across different cpu cores (there are 56 available so I really want to make full use of it)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try treating `G` as a database - so instead that it will be shared by all the sub-processes - they will be able to get info from it and do what they need